# Getting error while using Oxford dictionary API in php

Tags: php, api, dictionary

Hey you unknown friend myself Amaan, I'm using Oxford Dictionary API for my project but I'm getting error.
Here's my code

```
<?php

include_once 'dictionary.class.php';


$dictionary = new Dictionary("APP ID", "APP KEY", "en-gb");


$dictionary->newDictionaryRequest("Pizza");


$dictionary->setResult(0);


echo "<h1>Dictionary Class Results - ".$dictionary->word."</h1> - status: ".$dictionary->errors['status'];
echo "<b>Word:</b> ".$dictionary->word;
echo "<br><b>Definition:</b> ".$dictionary->getDefinition();
echo "<br><b>Short Definition:</b> ".$dictionary->getShortDefinition();
echo "<br><b>Example:</b> ".$dictionary->getExample(0);
echo "<br><b>Example 2:</b> ".$dictionary->getExample(1);
echo "<br><b>Lexical:</b> ".$dictionary->getLexical();
echo "<br><b>Phonetic:</b> ".$dictionary->getPhonetic();
echo "<br><b>Origin:</b> ".$dictionary->getOrigin();
echo "<br><b>Language:</b> ".$dictionary->API_LANG;
echo "<br><b>Audio:</b> <audio controls><source src='".$dictionary->getAudio()."' type='audio/mpeg'>Your browser does not support HTML audio</audio><br>";

echo "<br></br>Using result set: <b>".$dictionary->selected_result."</b>";
echo "<br></br>Total result sets available from request: <b>".$dictionary->num_returned_results."</b>";


?>
```

> **Error is this :-** Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Dictionary::setResult() on this line :-
>   `$dictionary->setResult(0);`

Here is the link of [dictionary.class.php](https://github.com/MarkFirman/Oxford-Dictionaries-API-Wrapper/blob/master/dictionary.class.php)

Comment: I'm not sure what else we can add to the error message - the class you've linked doesn't have a method called `setResult`

Comment: To be fair though, the Readme mentions "_$dictionary->setResult(1);_". Maybe consult the author of that package

Comment: @kerbholz I tried this but it is not working

Comment: What kerbholz is saying is that the Readme is outdated. When you check the history of the class, you can see the method was removed. The author forgot to remove it from the Readme.

Comment: From that package: "_/* Set the result to use - some words might have multiple meanings ('bark') - use this method to switch between different meanings *//* This is only required if you want to specify a result set other than the default */_" I guess you can just omit/remove `$dictionary->setResult(0);`

Comment: Thank you kerbholz for your suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**

If you also getting error in this line 
`$dictionary->setResult(0);`

**Answer is :**

Remove this line `$dictionary->setResult(0);`.

**Why :**

This line is optional, if you want more than one result set use this else remove this  line from code.

**Alternative :**

Display an message if result set is not more than one set.

**Advice :**

Read the [Readme.md](https://github.com/MarkFirman/Oxford-Dictionaries-API-Wrapper/blob/master/README.md) File carefully.

> Special thanks to @kerbholz

Thank you.